# Git Ignore tracked files

Tags: github

If any directory is ignored through `.gitignore` that contains a few important files that are committed to repository but also contains some unwanted temp files which are generated.
What will happen if important file is modified, will this file be ignored by git?

Comment: If a file has already been committed to the repository, then adding it, or its parent folder, to `.gitignore` should have no effect.  In such a case, you would first need to `git rm --cached` the file(s) in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File already tracked in Git are not affected by `.gitignore`.

Any changes to tracked files will show up in `git status`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it is helpful

Comment: I am not able to up vote because my reputation is less than 15 points